# Jsoup 404 error

Tags: java, html, connection, http-status-code-404, jsoup

I am new with Jsoup but I can't understand why I receive a 404 error when trying to obtain a page, even if the page is accessible from browser and I don't use any proxys. I have tried with the following code:

```
private static Document connect() {
    String url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/real-madrid/startseite/verein/418";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

and I receive the exception message:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/real-madrid/startseite/verein/418
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
at ro.pago.ucl2015.UCLWebParser.connect(UCLWebParser.java:27)
at ro.pago.ucl2015.UCLWebParser.main(UCLWebParser.java:16)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that the site doesn't allow bots and it will throw a 
404 error response in case it doesn't locate the User-Agent headers. 
The below works as it sets the user agent headers

```
private static Document connect() {
    String url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/real-madrid/startseite/verein/418";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
               .referrer("http://www.google.com")              
               .get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

> **User Agent**
>
> The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) identifies the client software
>   originating the request, using a "User-Agent" header, even when the
>   client is not operated by a user.
>
> ---
>
> **Referrer** (I don't think this is necessary)
>
> HTTP referer (originally a misspelling of referrer) is an HTTP header
>   field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI or IRI)
>   that linked to the resource being requested.

Just to provide full service I would advise you to set the timeout period for your requests. The default is 3 seconds, if the server takes longer than that you will receive 
an exception. Bellow follows your code with timeout setter. Set it to zero for the longest possible period.

```
private static Document connect() {
    String url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/real-madrid/startseite/verein/418";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
               .referrer("http://www.google.com") 
               .timeout(1000*5) //it's in milliseconds, so this means 5 seconds.              
               .get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. I'm sorry I can't upvote you answer, you deserve it. Could you explain what's with userAgent and referrer methods; What is their role? Thanks again

Comment: No problem. The fact that you took the extra step to thank me with a comment, is more than enough. I'm glad I could help. 
P.S. Check my update.

Answer (score 14):

If in case you are getting response code 404 , you can skip that url

Use ignoreHttpErrors(true), will surely solve your problem

```
Document doc3 = null;
    try {
        doc3 = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @user25 why you want to load a url that throws 404 - which actually doesn't exists.

Comment: it exists, I just needed to log on first on the main page before trying to loading another page of the same site, some functionality works only when you are logged on

Comment: Then I believe u need to checkout some methods to pass extra credentials along with url

Comment: yes I already solved it, found out how to log in and then I can use cookies to load different pages